# How to integrate the WSO2 Data Services 3.0 with Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle10g, wso2, wso2-data-services-server

We use Windows Server 8 with Oracle 10g (R 10.2.0.2).

We believe that the Oracle JDBC Jar is correct, we tested some possibilities.

The problem now when we tested the connection is: "provided data source type not supported".

Anybody have any suggestion?

Thanks so much!

Comment: How did you configure the data source? Could you please share the configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe there must be an issue with your datasource configuration defined in master-datasources.xml or any other *-datasources.xml you are using in your environment. Please double check whether the following line is defined properly in your datasource configuration. All the RDBMS databases should be configured having the definition type as "RDBMS".

```
<definition type="RDBMS">
```

A complete sample datasource configuration for your requirement is depicted below.

```
<datasource>
            <name>testds</name>
            <description>The datasource used for registry and user manager</description>
            <jndiConfig>
                <name>jdbc/testds</name>
            </jndiConfig>
            <definition type="RDBMS">
                <configuration>
                    <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE</url>
                    <username>test</username>
                    <password>test</password>
                    <driverClassName>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driverClassName>
                    <maxActive>50</maxActive>
                    <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                    <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                    <validationQuery>SELECT 1 FROM DUAL</validationQuery>
                    <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
                </configuration>
            </definition>
        </datasource>
```

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Prabath